# How to export a Twine story to a Twee file?

Tags: twine

I'm new to Twine, and would like to export the story I'm working on to a Twee file.  As far as I can tell, it is only available as an HTML file stored in ~/Documents/Twine, and I don't see a way to export in the user interface.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add [Entweedle](https://www.maximumverbosity.net/twine/Entweedle/) as a story format, you'll be able to export as an HTML file which displays the Twee source, which you can then copy into a file.

It's possible to automate copying it into file with WebDriver, but it's hard to say setting that up is worth it over just doing it manually.